# Ajustar texto para alinear

Tags: c++

En un proyecto debo mostrar por pantalla lo siguiente:

```
La Jornada con mas puntos es la 5 con 344 puntos.
> Jornada 5
-----------------------------------------
R._Madrid 84 - 91 Barcelona
  Manresa 84 - 85 Joventut
```

### El problema esta en que a mi me queda algo asi:

```
R._Madrid 84 - 91 Barcelona
Manresa 84 - 85 Joventut
```

Que podría hacer para que se alinee en función del guion?
He pensado en contar la cantidad de caracteres del nombre, pero al ser un tipo de dato no string, creo que no funcionará.

Gracias

Comment: estas en lo correcto.. vas a tener que contar la cantidad de caracteres por linea y agregar espacios segun corresponda..

Comment: Y se puede hacer aunque no sea un string? con la función strlen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en plan manual, es decir, calcular el tamaño de cada texto y añadir espacios a conveniencia o puedes hacer uso de las utilidades de la librería estándar

opción 1: libreria `iomanip`

```
std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(12) << "Real Madrid"
          << ' ' << 84 << " - " << 91 << ' '
          << "Barcelona" << '\n';
```

Salida:

```
 Real Madrid 84 - 91 Barcelona
     Manresa 84 - 85 Juventud
```

opción 2: modificadores `cout`

```
std::cout.fill(' ');
std::cout.width(12);
std::cout << "Real Madrid"
          << ' ' << 84 << " - " << 91 << ' '
          << "Barcelona" << '\n';
```

Se podría formatear cada campo para jugar también con las alineaciones a derechas e izquierdas, pero se complica la lectura y comprensión del ejemplo

Comment: Genial no conocía esas posibilidades gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `cout` pero debes saber que cout tiene algunos métodos que te ayudan a formatear la salida.

**WIDTH**

```
    cout <<"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" <<endl;
    // le asigno un espacio de 25 caracteres a cada equipo
    cout.width(25); cout << left << "NOMBRE DEL EQUIPO 1";
    // le asigno un espacio de 1 al guion
    cout.width(1); cout << "-";
    //le asigno su espacio y lo alineo a la derecha
    cout.width(25); cout << right << "nombre segundo equipo" <<endl;
```

Puedes revisar mas de esto en [referencia width](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/?kw=width)